# How to build a Simple django live dashboard

Tags: bokeh, plotly-dash, django-2.1

I'm trying to make a dashboard which updates live using Django framework. Since i'm a newbie to Django, don't have an idea on how to build a live dashboard. I tried SO and few github repositories which didn't help me, either they have only a live plot or a way complex dashboard, which i don't understand. Please help to provide any simple Django live dashboard example, which i can use as a base to build my dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you break the problem in chewable chunks.

For example:

For the backend:
What does a dashboard consist of?
- It can contain workspaces(an abstraction - to contain widgets)
- Each workspace then can contain widgets
- Widget can be of different types based on visualizations

- Bar chart widget
- Line chart widget
- Stacked chart widget
- ...

Each widget will also have controls like date filters or other filters

You would also need a way to filter your data, so, some abstraction which gives you data based on widget type and settings that user chooses on the frontend.

For the frontend:
- Choose a charting library and based on that you can fetch configurations for the  widgets from the backend
- A way to poll your backend periodically for getting live updates

This is not at all a fully baked architecture. Go and take a look at https://django-dash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#screenshots for a good architecture which I'm exploring myself.

I hope it helps. Happy coding!